# Select POST/GET parameters with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

How can I select a list of POST/GET parameters with an Regular Expression? For Example something like:

```
request.POST.regex(/^inputs_/)
```

Comment: @Anurag Actually I need to get all parameters that `startswith` something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
input_keys = [key for key in request.POST if re.match(r"^inputs_", key)]
```

that said, a regex would be overkill here:

```
input_keys = [key for key in request.POST if key.startswith("inputs_")]
```

Comment: Excuse me for this question, I'm not familiar with this syntax, what's this?

Comment: It's known as [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).